How to add text on PCB Pads?
How to add text on PCB Pads in Altium Designer
I just this Image Im Interest to known how to do this


I'd be surprised if any software has some built-in way of doing this, but you should be able to do it manually with fill zones and knockout text.

I'd be looking for some way to get the node name onto the copper layer
